# Allowing a specific user of Azure SQL Server Database to connect only through a specific IP

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

In Azure Server/Database firewall we can set the IP from which connections to the SQL Server can be made. However if I set any IP address eg. 101.202.203.204, then all users of the database can connect through that IP.

There is one user which is used by the application. I do not want anyone to connect to the production database using this username. This connection should only be permissible from the VM hosting the application in Azure.

In SQL Server there is a feature named **Logon trigger** wherein I can determine the username and the IP address from where the connection is being made and accordingly refuse if the connection request is invalid. This feature would have been helpful, however this feature is not available in the Azure SQL Server which I am using as a service.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MitchWheat, that is a good suggestion. But there would be someone who knows the password. I also want to prevent that person from using the credentials meant for the application. In short, I do not want anybody other than the application in the VM to connect to the database using that username.

Comment: If the SQL Database firewall only allows access from the one IP address (your vm), perhaps block access from this particular user to login to that vm? Just don't provide the login credentials to the vm. I'm sure there are other ways, but... this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it's not a programming problem (and it's too broad, with several potential ways of solving it).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is the *best* way to secure a SQL Server/SQL Azure database, but technically you can do this using a login trigger where you check the user name and the IP address in the trigger.  There's an example in the docs for triggers here that is basically what you are requesting (checks the login name).  You'd just need to join with sys.dm_exec_connections and validate that the IP address is what you wanted.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Dear @Conor, thanks for your help. But as I have explained earlier as well, the Logon Trigger feature unfortunately does not exist/function for Azure SQL Server when used as a service.